# Why ``module build failed`` error when trying to use fontawesom icons in my react project?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, font-awesome

I am following the fontawesome documentation on how to add icons with react.
https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons

I have added `babel.config.js` and `babel-plugin-macros.config.js` files in my `root directory`. Code for both of those file could be viewed in the documentation link attached.

I am getting the error as:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Caching was left unconfigured. Babel's plugins, presets, and .babelrc.js files can be configured
for various types of caching, using the first param of their handler functions:
```

i added  `api.cache(true)` in my `babel.config.js` file but still the error persists.

Can anyone identify why this error is showing up?

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71724999/13434851

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, if you used create-react-app you could try ejecting the project and following the steps (I failed), but the way I got it to work is to follow https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/react/

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@latest

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faGear } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
const gearIcon = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGear} />
...
render(<> {gearIcon} </>);
```

Comment: that is not dynamic import

Answer (score 0):

change the `babel.config.js` to `babelrc.config.js`

Comment: Can you specify a babel version that this works for? Is it valid for all babel versions?