# Error: Caching was left unconfigured. Babel's plugins when I installed Font Awesome to my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, font-awesome

I would like to use Font Awesome in my React app, but when I have install npm of [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/react/) I had this error:

```
Error: Caching was left unconfigured. Babel's plugins, presets, and .babelrc.js files can be configured
  for various types of caching, using the first param of their handler functions:
  module.exports = function(api) {
    // The API exposes the following:
    // Cache the returned value forever and don't call this function again.
    api.cache(true);
    // Don't cache at all. Not recommended because it will be very slow.
    api.cache(false);
    // Cached based on the value of some function. If this function returns a value different from
    // a previously-encountered value, the plugins will re-evaluate.
    var env = api.cache(() => process.env.NODE_ENV);
    // If testing for a specific env, we recommend specifics to avoid instantiating a plugin for
    // any possible NODE_ENV value that might come up during plugin execution.
    var isProd = api.cache(() => process.env.NODE_ENV === "production");
    // .cache(fn) will perform a linear search though instances to find the matching plugin based
    // based on previous instantiated plugins. If you want to recreate the plugin and discard the
    // previous instance whenever something changes, you may use:
    var isProd = api.cache.invalidate(() => process.env.NODE_ENV === "production");
    // Note, we also expose the following more-verbose versions of the above examples:
    api.cache.forever(); // api.cache(true)
    api.cache.never();   // api.cache(false)
    api.cache.using(fn); // api.cache(fn)
    // Return the value that will be cached.
    return { };
  };
```

and this is my dev dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0"
  }
```

I have created 2 new files like in tutorial
babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  return {
    plugins: ['macros'],
  }
}
```

and babel-plugin-macros.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  'fontawesome-svg-core': {
    'license': 'free'
  }
}
```

but I have still this bug

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For fix this bug I chenged a litte babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
      plugins: ['macros'],
    }
  }
```

Comment: I add `api.cache(true);` can't work . when i change to `api.cache.forever()` , it's fixed.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well - none of the other solutions here worked in my case.

Comment: This worked for me, but would encounter the same error when i ran `yarn build` . I had to delete node_modules and reinstall packages: `rm -rf node_modules; yarn;` for bundling to work again.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for me is to change the format of my babel config from babel.config.js to .babelrc. After that I didn't see any of that kind of error.
Go [here](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-macros/blob/main/other/docs/user.md) for more explanation.

Comment: This one helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and adding the `api.cache(true)` line didn't work for me (neither any suggestion posted here), so I cleaned the babel cache `rm -rf node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/`  and the issue is gone.

Answer (score -3):

1. Press F1
2. Go to settings.json
3. Set "json.schemaDownload.enable": true
4. Reload VSCode

Comment: How has VSCode got _anything_ to do with the OP's question?